# Applications of Magneto-optic effects

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, optics

I know that Faraday effect is widely used in modulators and optical isolators.

I also know that Magnetooptic Kerr Effect (MOKE) is used for surface characterisation.

But what are the uses for Cotton-Mouton and Voigt effects? Are there any other effects with practical uses?

Comment: -1 Have you searched the internet using your title?

Comment: @sammygerbil yes I have searched and I noticed that there's no practical uses for Cotton-Mouton and Voigt, but I came here to make sure.